# Display data json to table in react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, user-interface, frontend

I'm going to build a web with react js. I'm very new to react so I have a problem to make `CRUD`. For the first I want to display some data `json` to table. I have file .js that named `keranjang.js`. it contains jsx to display the table. and I have another named `barang.js` and want to fill it with the method named `tampildata()` used to hold json data for example `{"nama_barang" : "bolu", "harga" : "10000"}`. How I write the method? and how do I call the method and data to display that data into the existing table in `keranjang.js`? Hope everyone helps me.

Comment: Can you post some code showing what you've already tried?

Comment: You are trying to access method that is present in one js file returning json and want to display that json in another js file that having table ui. Correct?

Comment: yes you're right bro

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that you trying to call external file's method in current component. In your `barang.js` file export your function that holds json data like

```
export function tampildata() {
    return [{ "firstname": "first", "lastname": "f"}, {"firstname": "second", "lastname": "l"}];
}
```

or

```
export default {
  tampildata() {
    return [{ "firstname": "first", "lastname": "f"}, {"firstname": "second", "lastname": "l"}];
  }
};
```

Then in your `keranjang.js` file import your `tampildata` method and call that method in `componentDidMount` and set state like below

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { tampildata } from 'barang';

class TableComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            json: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
                json: tampildata()
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.state.json.map((data, i) => {
                            return (
                                <tr key={i}>
                                    <td>{data.firstname}</td>
                                    <td>{data.lastname}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <TableComponent />, 
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Here is the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elumalaiit/Ln1gLa8g/1/). Hope this will helps you!

Comment: hey, but i have problem with exporting the method from first .js file. how to export the method? is this ..export function tampildata() {}.. exactly to write it? because there's error.  it says "unexpected token"

Comment: Yes this the way `export function tampildata() {}` export method and import method as `import { tampildata } from 'barang';`.

Comment: Please see the updated answer that will helps you! Make sure you have `presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'babel-preset-stage-0']` in your webpack configuration.

Comment: how i configure webpack?

Comment: Here is the good source to go http://ccoenraets.github.io/es6-tutorial-react/setup/